# coloured histogram variable in rstudio

Tags: r, variables, colors, histogram

From this link[EXCEL FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjuonfr7jklg073/manze%20ZAMBELLONI.xlsx?dl=0)

I wrote that code

```
library(ggplot2)

manze<-manze_ZAMBELLONI
manze$DAGE<-as.numeric(manze$DAGE)

ggplot(manze, aes(DAGE))+
  geom_histogram(col="black", aes(fill=RPRO), bins=20)+
  geom_density(aes(y=50*..count..), alpha=0.2)`
```

And got that nice histogram:

[image: histogram giving a view of the total amount of heifers in a dairy operation by age, and reproductive status represented by colour]

So the question is: for several reasons, sometimes I prefer working with default Rstudio histograms, and I think I know how to do that, except I don't know how to colour by reproductive status, so that's what I am getting

```
hist(manze$DAGE, breaks = 30, prob=T, col="grey") 
grid() 
lines(density(manze$DAGE), col="blue", lwd=3)
axis(side=1, at=seq(0,900,50))
```

[image: same histogram by Rstudio default]

So; how to colour by reproductive status adding an order to this second syntax?

Many thanks and kind regards.

Comment: Wich library did you use for the 2nd plot?

Comment: no library: default histograms. Sorry, I forgot adding code:

Comment: manze<-manze_ZAMBELLONI

hist(manze$DAGE, breaks = 30, 
     prob=T, col="grey")
grid()
lines(density(manze$DAGE), col="blue", lwd=3)
axis(side=1, at=seq(0,900,50))

Comment: so I would like to get RIPRO status coloured. Thanks.

Comment: please show some data using e.g. `dput()` rather than posting links.

Comment: But you can try `hist(mtcars$mpg, prob=T,breaks = 30,border=0, ylim = c(0,0.6));
hist(subset(mtcars,vs == 1)$mpg, prob=T, breaks = 30, add=T, col="grey");
hist(subset(mtcars,vs == 0)$mpg, prob=T, breaks = 30, add=T, col="red")`

Comment: Many thanks, but I think this way I will not have one single density line for all colored variables, like in geom_histogram (ggplot2) option, and I would be interested in having that.